# Running C++ app from the Windows command line

Tags: c++, compilation, cygwin

I have installed cygwin in order to compile C++ source code. At this stage I can run the C++ app by invoking it directly via icon. But once I type g++ on the cmd command line I receive 'Access denied' message. That command works fine on cygwin terminal window. How to deal with this issue? This questions has been trig-erred by the another issue which is present on this forum. 
It is that I cannot see the output on Eclipse IDE once I run the C++ app (no errors). I though t the thing that I receive that 'Access denied' message on cmd might be the culprit for the mentioned trouble. Just trying out all the things.
Best regards

Comment: Why do you need to use g++ on the cmd command line instead of just in the cygwin terminal? If you elaborate you might get a better answer. Unless you mean you are trying to actually run your application in the cmd window, in which case you may need to set the permissions on the .exe in cygwin properly with chmod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar to cygwin, but theres a code you can try. It is similar to "sudo" on linux, and it gives you more privileges... 
It's called "runas". Take a look on this site: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

Did you add cygwin to your path in windows?

Comment: C:\cygwin\bin Your folder might be different check.
You now should add it to the PATH environment variable. You do that by following:
   Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Comment: Yes, and that is why I can invoke exe file by only clicking on it as I have mentioned already.